# Get array with json object out of a string

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

I have a java spring boot project that makes an REST API call and one element of the returned json is as follows:

`"args": "[[\"element_1\"],[\"element_2\"],[\"{\\\"payload\\\":\\\"{\\\"Header\\\": \\\"Header_title\\\", \\\"Content\\\": \\\"Content of the payload\\\"}\\\"}\"]]"`

My objective is to get the JsonObject "payload". I can get the string using
`JsonObject argString = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(originalJsonObject.get("args").toString());`
(using the package com.google.gson.JsonObject) but I can't get the two-dimensional array out of the string.

Comment: "can't get"? What happens?

Comment: @tgdavies I get an Exception because it can't be converted. The exception itself varies accordingly to the methods that I tried, using the `jsonParser.parse()` that I mention in the question I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: `.

Comment: What's the value of `originalJsonObject.get("args").toString()`?

Comment: It's in the question: `"[[\"element_1\"],[\"element_2\"],[\"{\\\"payload\\\":\\\"{\\\"Header\\\": \\\"Header_title\\\", \\\"Content\\\": \\\"Content of the payload\\\"}\\\"}\"]]"`

Answer (score 0):

The part of data that you've included actually is a key `args` with a string value `[[\"element_1\"],[\"element_2\"],[\"{\\\"payload\\\":\\\"{\\\"Header\\\": \\\"Header_title\\\", \\\"Content\\\": \\\"Content of the payload\\\"}\\\"}\"]]`. So it is correct that you cannot get these contents decoded through a method on the existing Json, but you can take the string and parse it to a json array as follows:

```java
JsonElement jsonElem = new JsonParser().parse(argString);
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElem.getAsJsonArray();
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object` with your solution. I can already get a JsonElement with `originalJsonObject.get("args")`, but I can't do anything with it.

Comment: I've ran this code with the provided string and it prints all elements in the json array. Are you sure that the exception is from this code? Can you check whether the input is the same as well? Where are you getting the exception on?

Comment: With that method i can get the string out of the arrays but I still don't have a JsonObject. I get the string `"{\"payload\":\"{\Header\": ...` (starting with double quotes) and this string cannot be converted to a json object.

Comment: Ah I see. The problem there is that again the value in the json array is a string, and that this string is not in valid json syntax (the quotes of the string within that string are not properly escaped). If the response is always similar, then you can use `String.substring()` or a regex to get the value of interest. If in any way possible, I would however change what generates this data to generate one single json object without wrapping all inner objects in a string. This indicates that something weird is going on there.